# Mysql node function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to make a call to the mysql server with node and store data into a fucntion:

```
async function getData(uri){
let data = await esisteMysql(uri);
console.log(data);
}


function esisteMysql(uri) {
    connection.query(`select * from data where url = '${uri}'`, function (error, row) {
      if(error) throw error;
      else {
        if(row && row.length){
          console.log('FOUND');
          //console.log(row);
          return row;
        }else{
          console.log('NOT FOUND');
          return row = null;
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

It doesn't work, it returns an undefined. I can log data only if I print it in esisteMysql with console.log(row);

Answer (score 0):

Your `esisteMysql()` needs to produce a promise in order to work with `await`.  It might look something like:

```
async function getData(uri) {
    let data = await esisteMysql(uri);
    console.log(data);
}

function esisteMysql(uri) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query(`select * from data where url = '${uri}'`, function (error, row) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(row);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

See https://javascript.info/async for more.